# Detect Entity SQL command text

Tags: .net, entity-framework, security, sql-injection

Although standards and training tell our developers not to use "Entity SQL command text" as it makes code susceptable to SQL injection attacks - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/security-considerations#security-considerations-for-queries - it would be nice to confirm this using some mechanism such as a parser.
Does anyone know if it is possible to detect any Entity SQL commands during development or test as part of a defence in depth agains SQL injection?

Comment: If you *don't* use eSQL you won't have any issues. If you use parameterized eSQL you won't have issues. You don't need a parser for that. You probably need code reviews, especially if you care about defence-in-depth. A parser won't help you at all if the rest of the code is vulnerable, or if you map to stored procedures that concatenate query strings themselves

Comment: In fact, if you find people resorting to Entity SQL you should ask *why*? Quite often it's a sign of desing issues. Not because a guideline says not to, but because it's meant for special cases. Is the *model* wrong? Are they trying to do something unsuitable for ORMs like reporting? Why eSQL instead of mapping to a view or stored procedure?

Comment: Agree with the above. But with 80+ developers would be nice to have an automated step too.

Comment: That's called "code review". You can't use a tool to do it for you, *especially* when you have big teams. You can use tools to make it easier and friendlier. You can use tools like Resharper, code analyzers in Visual Studio or SonarCube to check the code, but in the end you have to design it properly. eSQL isnt' bad just like Dapper and parameterized queries aren't bad.

Comment: In the simplest case, just don't use Entity SQL. Don't use EntityCommand objects or the `SqlQuery` method. You can find any instances simply by searching all code for `EntityCommand` or `SqlQuery(`